# Neural Network to find patterns in a sequence of numbers

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, mxnet

Given a series of numbers produced by X unique functions, let’s say 12 for this example, is there a way to build a neural network to determine the 12 unique functions which generate the numbers, as well as which of the functions was used to generate the numbers?

Example, if `f(x) = a` ghen `f(x’) = b` through l

Example sequence would be:

a, c, g, f, a, k, d, e, j, j, c, k, l… etc Could you identify that function which generates a, b, c…l?

Simpler example with 3 functions:

```
a = f(x) = x + 1
b = f(x) = x * 2
c = f(x) = x / 2
```

a, b, c given 2 as the input would be
3, 4, 1
The sequence could be:

3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 1, 3, 4

Of course, the functions would never be as simple as the examples.

Could you determine that `a = x + 1`, `b = x * 2` and `c = x/2`?

Comment: Are the functions restricted to a particular form? And how is the input generated? e.g. 2 in the example you gave.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a neural network as a glorified function approximator. In order to approximate a function, you need to have example input and outputs. If you only have outputs (like the sequence you're referring to), then the answer is most likely "no, not possible". If you do have the input/output examples, then you can have a recurrent network that can predict which function was used to generate that sequence.

In order to drive the formula for each function, you need a separate network for each of the possible functions and you would need your network to output an arithmetic expression tree. This isn't easy, but doable, if the size of the tree can be constrained. In a nutshell, you'd want your network to output a distribution over operators (+,-,*, etc.) as well as constants (1, 2, etc.) that are used as lhs and rhs in each operator.

Personally I haven't never tried anything like this, but if you do, I'd love to know how the training goes!